# How to make a column field and its value same for all the users

Tags: php, mysql, row

I have got two tables one is users(id is primary key) and other is movie(movieid is primary key and id is foreign key). when one user logged in and submitted a form which contains info of a particular movie it is saved in movie table by creating a unique movieid but when another user submit the same form of the same movie it creates new movie id which i don't want

Ex: lets take a movie Titanic when a paticular user submits a form related to titanic movieid column of that user should be same, but for me it is creating new movieid for every user

```
        if ($result) {
            $movieid = $stmt->insert_id;
            $stmt->close();
```

This is small code which i have used to create movieid
I think my code creates unique movieid for each user. I want to replace this code with another which gives me same movieid for every user who submit form related to a particular movie
can anyone help me with this

Thank you

Comment: since `movieid` is your primary key you can't have it repeated in the same table. If i understand correctly what you need is a third table, let's call it `reviews` for now where you have a `reviewid` as primary key and a `movieid` as a foreign key, this way any number of users can submit your form for the same movie

Comment: @Daniel thank you for response, Yeah i think i should create new table

Comment: You're welcome @karthik, good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 0):

The snippet of code shown in the question does not cause new values to be created.

The `insert_id` function retrieves a value that was *already* generated for an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column by a previous `INSERT` statement.

What the code did *before* the call to `insert_id` is what "created" new AUTO_INCREMENT values. And what the code does *after*, with the retrieved value, could be anything the code wants to do.

---

In terms of the observed behavior, because we can't see the table definitions, because we don't see the SQL INSERT statement that was executed, or any of the related code, we'd just be guessing which column is AUTO_INCREMENT, which table was just inserted to, where the AUTO_INCREMENT value came from.  So it's not really possible to give any advice about how to change the behavior of the program.

---

We can advise that we should gain an understanding of what the MySQL `LAST_INSERT_ID` function does if we are going to use it. (Note that mysqli insert_id is a wrapper for the MySQL function.)

from the MySQL Reference Manual:

> With no argument, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns a BIGINT UNSIGNED (64-bit) value representing the first automatically generated value successfully inserted for an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column as a result of the most recently executed `INSERT` statement. The value of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` remains unchanged if no rows are successfully inserted.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id